# After creating a build from expo, the Apk needs metro bundle to run. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, lexicon

I have created a build for android in expo. I got a standalone link which helped me download an Apk link. I installed that apk in my mobile device but it is not getting connected with the backend (api). When I run metro bundler on my development machine, then the apk works perfectly, it fetches the data from api and displays it.

[image: If I were to run my build from Expo Go then it would be understandable that it requires metro bundler to be started.]

[image: But I am using an individual standalone APK.]

[image: Info on standalone app]